Circuit without Thevenin equivalent?
(I edited heavily my original post because it was based on my serious misunderstanding of a textbook  exercise. However the main question remains valid as explained below.)
It appears to me (and also pointed out in comments below) that the following circuit does not have a Thevenin equivalent.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I take branch directions  as follows:
\$V_1\$ from 0 to 1, \$R_2\$ from 2 to 1, \$R_3\$ from 0 to 2, \$I_4\$ from 2 to 3, \$R_5\$ from 3 to 4.  For clarity, the CCCS is \$I_4=8i_{R_2}\$.
To find the Thevenin equivalent I connect as load a voltage source \$V_L\$ from 4 to 0. To solve the circuit I take loops \$V_1R_2R_3\$, \$R_3I_4R_5V_L\$; call the loop currents \$p_1,p_2\$. In \$V_1R_2R_3\$  we have:
$$
V_1+R_2p_1+R_3(p_1-p_2)=0\Rightarrow 
5+10p_1+10(p_1-8i_2)=0\Rightarrow 
5+10p_1+10(p_1+8p_1)=0\Rightarrow p_1=-0.05.
$$
Then
$$
i_L=i_5=i_4=8i_2=-8p_1=0.40.
$$
In other words, the current through the load \$V_L\$ is \$i_L=0.40\$, independent of \$V_L\$. This cannot be attained by any Thevenin equivalent, because a Thevenin equivalent is a practical voltage source and must have characteristic \$i_{Th}=\frac{V_{Th}}{R_{Th}}\$.
Question 1: So does it follow that the circuit has no Thevenin equivalent?
Question 2: More generally, what conditions must a circuit satisfy to have a  Thevenin equivalent?
PS2: The analysis and conclusion remain valid if we use a resistor load \$R_L\$ instead of \$V_L\$. We cannot use a current source load \$I_L\$, because then we would get \$I_L=i_4=0.4\$  (by the same analysis as above). But \$i_L\$ can be arbitrary; it is not obliged to be \$I_L=0.4\$. In other words, the circuit with a current source load has no solution (or an infinity of solutions).
PS2: The circuit does have a Norton equivalent with \$I_{Nr}=0.4\$, \$R_{Nr}=\infty\$. In other words, it seems to me that the original can be replaced by an ideal current source.

@All - Although well-intentioned, the long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore comments so far have been moved to chat & should be continued there (see link in the comment below). || As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here may be deleted without notice. Keep it in chat now, please! || Any improvement / clarification to the question decided during the chat, should be made via an [edit], not as a comment. When someone has enough information to post an answer, please answer it as usual. TY

Comments have been moved to this chatroom and discussion should be continued there. Please do not continue the discussion in comments here.

After several rounds of comments (which can be found here) the best answer I got  (from G36) is that the circuit is equivalent to an ideal current source and hence has no Thevenin equivalent.
The larger question (what are the conditions for a circuit to have a Thevenin equivalent?) remains unanswered but there is some interesting material by Periblepsis (see here) and in the book Basic Circuit Theory (Desoer and Kuh) p. 669.
